# HighCharts: Any way to control positioning or grouping of legend items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

By default, Highcharts fills horizontal legends with legend items from left to right, introducing a line break between items when the next item would overflow the legend's bounding box.

I would like to be able to control where such line breaks occur, so that (for example) instead of *this*:

[image: Legend items with default positioning]

I could visually group the "Target" and "Actual" items together, and then list the remaining series on subsequent lines like *this*:

[image: Legend items with programmatically-controlled positioning]

Using [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML) and [labelFormatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter), I've tried a few different approaches involving <span>s, <div>s and styling to try to achieve this, but none of them have had any effect. The one approach I did manage to make work (from which I generated the second image above) is horribly kludgey, and probably can't be easily generalized for use in real code.

I'm thinking this ought to be a fairly simple thing to do, and I suspect that I'm merely overlooking some existing Highcharts feature that would do it. 
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing built it to Highcharts to allow this. For strict control of legend layout, building your own outside of the chart is best solution that I have seen.  (search "highcharts external legend" for examples)

Comment: @jlbriggs - Thanks for the pointer, even though it's pointing in a direction different than I'd hoped. :-)  Seems a shame, considering how much effort would probably be needed to externally replicate all the existing features of Highcharts legends, compared to how little (I imagine) it might take Highcharts to add some minimal layout-control capabilities to their API.

Comment: I advice you to post your suggestion in our [uservoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api).  Meantime you can prepare your legend ans HTML and then call [show/hide ](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.show) on series.

Comment: The effort to replicate is not all that bad, actually, and you gain a lot of control. But I do agree that there should be significantly more powerful layout options built in - I prefer to keep everything contained in Highcharts..